# What is the Mockito dependency for scala version 2.11.12, PLAY framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, mockito, tdd

I am new to scala and I have been trying to write tests in tdd approach. I am importing Mockito for writing tests. 
But the following line isn't recognized.

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    C:\Users\indu.c\Downloads\play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial>sbt test
[error] C:\Users\indu.c\Downloads\play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial\test\controllers\getControllerSpec.scala:10:12: object mockito is not a member of package org
[error] import org.mockito.Mockito._
[error]            ^
[error] C:\Users\indu.c\Downloads\play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial\test\controllers\getControllerSpec.scala:21:53: Symbol 'term org.mockito' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'value org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar.mockSettings'.
[error] Make sure that term mockito is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'MockitoSugar.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.
[error]   private val mockedEmployeeDAO: EmployeeDAO = mock[EmployeeDAO]
[error]                                                     ^
[error] C:\Users\indu.c\Downloads\play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial\test\controllers\getControllerSpec.scala:27:5: not found: value when
[error]     when(mockedEmployeeDAO.getEmployeestructure(6)).thenReturn(null)
[error]     ^
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 30 Jul, 2019 6:24:08 PM
```

Am I missing something in the build.sbt file.
Build file:

```
name := """play-scala-seed"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += guice
//libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
libraryDependencies += cache
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "0.30" % "test"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the wrong dependency.
It should probably be something like:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-scala_2.11" % "0.3.0" % "test"
```

Note as well that a `0.30` version does not exist.

For compatibility check:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-scala

Answer (score 2):

This is the right dependency for mokito :

`"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "3.0.0" % Test`

The version `0.30` is wrong.

I would suggest better to use mockito for scala :

`"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.5.12" % Test`

Here the link of documentation to have more information how to use it: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala

Comment: This is more likely the correct dependency, as the mvn repo list a optional dependency for `scalatest` to `mockito-core`. I'd just leave my answer around to inform the TO that there is a scala specific mockito dependency available.

Comment: @ginny I would suggest to use mockito for scala .